# an issue with the face materials

Tags: modeling, lighting, retopology

[image: face screenshot]

There's nothing wrong with this face it has four vertices and everything is fine

Why does it have that dot in the middle that reflects the light in a really strange way?

[image: vertices of the face]

Update: I've deleted the faces with the issue since I was on a tight deadline and started all over again, if the issue happened again I will post another question with the .blend file linked

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some form of Anisotrophy applied.
Please check the Anisotropic settings in the Principled BSDF settings:

[image]

Comment: thanks alot for your help I wil research what that means and fix it thanks alot

Comment: Don't mentioned it :) If my answer resolved your issue, could you please accept it by clicking the tick mark on the left? Cheers!

Comment: The user appears to be in *Solid* shading mode from the screenshots, which typically doesn't show shader effects in the viewport. So it doesn't seem likely anisotropy is the issue here.

Comment: That is really well spotted sir! @Hazem Yasyn If you are still having this issue, could you please share you .blend file and we can figure out what the problem is?

Comment: @SlickRed thanks a lot for the help guys, I still couldn't figure out the issues so I delete all the faces that had the same issue and started again from the normal faces with no issues, but thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply.